# Get preprocessor definition value using CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, c-preprocessor

Is there a not totally hacky way to get the value of a C preprocessor definition using CMake? For example I may want to do something like this to get the exact MSVC version.

```
if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "MSVC")
    get_preprocessor_value("_MSC_FULL_VER" msvc_version)
    if (msvc_version LESS 190023918)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Visual C++ 2015 Update 2 or later is required due to a bug in std::atomic.")
    endif ()
    target_compile_definitions(mytarget PRIVATE "_ENABLE_ATOMIC_ALIGNMENT_FIX")
endif ()
```

I made up `get_preprocessor_value()`. Is there a function that does that, or a simple way to do it. Obviously I can have CMake compile a simple program that prints it, and capture stdout, but I'm wondering if there is a built in function that does it for me.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in CMake function to do that, neither does CMake ship with a [standard module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-modules.7.html) to do something like that.

For the particular case of compiler version, CMake has the variable [`CMAKE_<LANG>_COMPILER_VERSION`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER_VERSION.html) (such as `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION` for C++).

If that variable doesn't provide enough information for you, your best bet is to use [`try_run()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/try_run.html) to compile & print the macro's value, as you've mentioned in the question. I don't find this hacky at all, I'd say it's actually a pretty idiomatic way of doing stuff like that in CMake.

Comment: Yeah I figured as much. Unfortunately I couldn't find anywhere what the values of CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION for MSVC actually are for each release. Ah well.

Comment: Actually scratch that, it's a fairly simple translation of the [`_MSC_FULL_VER` values](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Compilers/), e.g. 190023918 corresponds to `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION` of 19.0.23918.